# Dismissing a popupmenu from a dialog

Tags: android, popupmenu, dismiss

I have a popupmenu opening from an Imagview in a dialog. When the menuitem is clicked, I have a Text-To-Speech that speaks a countdown from 10 to 1. I want to close the menu once the menuitem is clicked. I tried popup.dismiss() and closeOptionsMenu() but no luck. Please help me out.

```
Imageview counter = (Imageview) findViewById(R.id.imgview);
counter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        PopupMenu countMenu = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this,counter);
        countMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.counter_menu, 
         countMenu.getMenu());

countMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new 
PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(final MenuItem menuItem) {
String selectedCount = menuItem.getTitle().toString();
countMenu.dismiss();
//Tried closeOptionsMenu(); too here but doesn't work

if(selectedCount.equals("Some String")
{
//TTS counter from 10 to 0
 return true;
}
countMenu.show();
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: I have posted my code here. Thanks

Comment: move your popup menu code out from counter.clicklistener and only call countMenu.show() from onClick()

Comment: I tried but doesn't work. The menu only dismisses once the TTS is finished.

Answer (score 1):

Return **true** will be outside of your **if** statement.You have placed the **return** statement inside the **if** statement and that's why it is closing after the count is completed.

Example code:

```
 countMenu.dismiss();

 return true;

 if(selectedCount.equals("Some String")
 {
 //TTS counter from 10 to 0
 }
```

Comment: if I add **return true** after countMenu.dismiss(); then the other part of that code would be unreachable. Please advise.

Comment: Then it is not possible friend.Actually you are wanting to get the item text and then you want to make a speach that what item has been selected.Then for that you have to wait until the tts finished to dismiss the popup menu.As per your need

Comment: is there any other way you can suggest where I can do the same without these issues?

Comment: You can call a parameterized method before you dismiss the popup menu.And pass the selected item value to that method.In that method you can try to check the equality and run the TTS